# the object has no attribute 'is_hidden' with django

Tags: python, django, forms, web, attributes

i am building a form with django, and i am getting this error:

'CharField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'

but the charField actually it has the attribute, as you can see:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Articulo

    fields = [
        'nombre_producto',
        'id_clasificacion_fk',
        'Descripcion',
        'long_descripcion',
        'precio',
        'cantidad',
        ]
    labels = {
        'nombre_producto': 'Nombre del producto',
        'id_clasificacion_fk': 'Clasificación del producto',
        'Descripcion': 'Corta descipción',
        'long_descripcion': 'Larga descipción',
        'precio': 'Precio del producto',
        'cantidad': 'Cantidad en inventario',
    }
    widgets = {
        'nombre_producto': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'id_clasificacion_fk': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'Descripcion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'long_descripcion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'precio': forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput),
        'cantidad': forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput),  
    }
```

anyone can help me? Thank you!.

Comment: your question sounds confusing. Share the error here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `widgets` dictionary, you're setting these two fields to `FormField` subtypes rather than `Widget` subtypes:

```
    'precio': forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput),
    'cantidad': forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput),
```

That's not right - `CharField` is not a widget. If you want to use the `NumberInput` widget for those fields, set it like this:

```
'precio': forms.NumberInput
```

If you want to change the default form field type for those model fields (my best guess at what you're trying to do with your existing values) use the `field_classes` dict or define the fields yourself. EG something like this (other fields omitted):

```
field_classes = {'precio': forms.CharField}
widgets = {'precio': forms.NumberInput}
```

Comment: Yes, 'precio': forms.NumberInput worked for me. That was i trying to do. Thank you!